# Python 3 dictionary returns different value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am making a small text rpg game to practice python and realise things i need to work on. This is my first problem and i do not yet have strong fundamentals on python. 
I have a nested dictionary and i would like to print a value from the dictionary but i get a completely different value. Why couls this be?

```
ZONENAME = ""
DESCRIPTION = "description" 
EXAMINATION = "info"
ANSWER = ""
SOLVED = False
UP = "up", "north"
DOWN = "down", "south"
LEFT = "left", "west"
RIGHT = "right", "east"

zonemap = {
    "a1": {
        ZONENAME: "Hometown",
        DESCRIPTION : "ioioi",
        EXAMINATION : "---",
        SOLVED : False,
        ANSWER : "",
        UP : "i",
        DOWN : "i",
        LEFT : "i",
        RIGHT : "a2",
    },
    "a2": {
        ZONENAME : "ii",
        DESCRIPTION : "....",
        EXAMINATION : "....",
        ANSWER : "your name",
        SOLVED : False,
        UP : "i",
        DOWN : "i",
        LEFT : "i",
        RIGHT : "a3",
    }
}

print(zonemap["a2"][ZONENAME])
```

Comment: `ZONENAME = ""` and `ANSWER = ""` have both same value. Dictionary cannot contain same keys - so you have a conflict here.

Comment: @AndrejKesely is right. Also I think you haven't fully understood what a dictionary is. You have keys that are tuples, which is possible, but as far as I can see not very useful for your use case.

Comment: You are probably not clear on how to define a dictionary. You *can* do what you do, which is to define variables that have the keys defined and then use the variables to define the dictionary's keys, but you could also just define the keys directly, i.e. `d = {'key': 'value'}` instead of `key = 'key'` and `d = {key: 'value'}`.

Answer (score 2):

To expound on Andrej's comment:

`ZONENAME` and `ANSWER` are both empty strings. When you use these as keys in `zonemap["a2"]`, the key is `""` (an empty string), **not** `"ZONENAME"` or `"ANSWER"`. So you first assign the value `"ii"` to the key `""`, then you assign the value `"your name"` to the key `""`. When you try to access the zone name through `zonemap["a2"][ZONENAME]`, you're actually accessing `zonemap["a2"][""]`, which holds the value `"your name"`.

Comment: The main point being that dictionaries can't have duplicate keys, so the value will be overwritten. I think you should open with that point. Don't rely on Andrej's comment hanging around; plenty of comments get deleted. Other than that, nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets delve a little deeper into your issue here, so you can get a better understanding of what is happening.

At the start of your code, you're setting the following variables;

```
ZONENAME = ""
DESCRIPTION = "description" 
EXAMINATION = "info"
ANSWER = ""
SOLVED = False
UP = "up", "north"
DOWN = "down", "south"
LEFT = "left", "west"
RIGHT = "right", "east"
```

The result of this, is when you call `ZONENAME` you get the response;

```
>>> ZONENAME
''
```

Now, lets have a look at your print statement, `print(zonemap["a2"][ZONENAME])`. Here you are calling, `dictonary["name of dictonary"][variable]` Since you have not enclosed your key name in quotes `''` you are directly referencing the variable itself, which as seen earlier is `''`.

So when you call `print(zonemap["a2"][ZONENAME])` you're actually saying; `print(zonemap["a2"][''])` which matches a key in your dictionary, which you set twice overriding the first value you set to that key.

What you have essentially done, it set the key names in the dictionary to the values of the variables you set prior to creating the dictionary.

You can see this by trying to access the key `ZONENAME`;

```
print(zonemap["a2"]['ZONENAME'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    print(zonemap["a2"]['ZONENAME'])
KeyError: 'ZONENAME'
```

The key does not exist, as it was never defined as `ZONENAME`. If you want to define the keys as the names you specified, you have to enclosed them in quotations.

```
zonemap = {
    "a1": {
        'ZONENAME': "Hometown",
        'DESCRIPTION': "ioioi",
        'EXAMINATION': "---",
        'SOLVED': False,
        'ANSWER': "",
        'UP': "i",
        'DOWN' : "i",
        'LEFT' : "i",
        'RIGHT' : "a2",
    },
    "a2": {
        'ZONENAME' : "ii",
        'DESCRIPTION' : "....",
        'EXAMINATION' : "....",
        'ANSWER' : "your name",
        'SOLVED' : False,
        'UP' : "i",
        'DOWN' : "i",
        'LEFT' : "i",
        'RIGHT' : "a3",
    }
}
```

This would now give you an accurate response when you call the key value in the dictionary.

```
>>> print(zonemap["a2"]['ZONENAME'])
ii
```

It would be a good opportunity for you to read up on dictionary's and how they work more in-depth.

[Dictonaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much! Very clear explanation! I'm going to study dictionaries more in depth. I first encountered dictionaries today and am little confused. Thanks again. :)